# Greek symbols in labels for bar chart in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, latex, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I would like to use greek symbols in the ylabels for my `barh()` chart. I tried the following but it didn't really work:

```
tplot = barh(mdata, 'BarWidth', 0.3);
set(gca,'xgrid','on')
lbl = {'$$\hat{\sigma}_1$$', '$$\hat{\sigma}_2$$', '$$\hat{\sigma}_3$$'};
box off
set(gca,'yticklabel',lbl)
h=findobj(gca,'type','text'); 
set(h,'Interpreter','latex')
```

I also tried:

```
set(gca,'TicklLabelInterpreter', 'tex')
```

When I do `get(gca)`, the property `TickLabelInterpreter` doesn't appear to be there at all! The version of MATLAB I am using is R2013a.

Please note that I specifically used `latex` as interpreter, rather than `tex`, because `tex` doesn't support `\hat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102053-how-can-i-make-the-xtick-and-ytick-labels-of-my-axes-utilize-the-latex-fonts-in-matlab-8-1-r2013a) quote by the MathWorks:

> The ability to make the Xtick labels and Ytick labels utilize the same
>   font as TEXT objects with LaTeX as their interpreter is not available
>   in MATLAB 8.1 (R2013a).

Therefore you need to remove the ylabels and create new ones manually as text objects on their own. You can then use the latex interpreter.

Here is a modified version of their example to fit your purpose:

```
clc
clear

y = [57,91,105];
tplot = barh(y, 'BarWidth', 0.3);

lbl = {'$$\hat{\sigma}_1$$', '$$\hat{\sigma}_2$$', '$$\hat{\sigma}_3$$'};

%% Generate figure and remove ticklabels

set(gca,'yticklabel',[])

%% Get tick mark positions
yTicks = get(gca,'ytick');

ax = axis; %Get left most x-position

%% Reset the ytick labels in desired font
for i = 1:length(yTicks)
%Create text box and set appropriate properties
     text(ax(1) - .3,yTicks(i),lbl{i},...
         'HorizontalAlignment','Right','interpreter', 'latex','FontSize',18);   
end
```

Output:

[image]